# Touchpad not working after startup - xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, startup, synaptics

I am using Xubuntu on Lenovo 3000 G430 Laptop. For touchpad to work everytime after startup:

1. I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (This will lock touchpad)
2. Now, light on my touchpad glows,
3. And then I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (This will unlock touchpad)
4. And then it starts to work.

I have tried:

```
xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
```

( 14 being the device id of touchpad. No luck )

I have tried (without success):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

`xinput --list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                           id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3     [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

How to make touchpad work directly after startup ? ( I want to skip pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> twice everytime. )

Comment: I'm having a similar problem where touchpad works on startup but not the setting "Disable touchpad while typing". After every startup I have to enter the Mouse and Touchpad settings, disable the specific touchpad device and then enable it again.

Did you find a solution for your problem. Perhaps a way to disable/enable device through a script?

Comment: It's been 4 years and that device is dead now sry 